# S/MIME download public key

Tags: php, email, encryption, smime

If I want to send an S/MIME encrypted email using [openssl_pkcs7_encrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-encrypt.php) from my webserver to a list of customers. Where do I get the public key of the recievers from?

I read about a Certificate Revocation List but not sure how to access it. Also it looks like it's only contains invalid keys.

If found this [search form](https://www.trustcenter.de/fcgi-bin/Search.cgi) but no idea...

Comment: You'd need your customers to provide their public keys... There's no canonical way of obtaining these.

Comment: CRLs contain IDs of *revoked* (claimed invalid) certificates so CRL even in theory wouldn't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need your customers to provide their public keys. There's no canonical way of obtaining these.

Comment: May I amend that the easiest way to do this is have them send you a signed message.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you purchase a cert from a trusted CA and encrypt email with your private key while the public key will be included in the cert sent along with the email. Take a look at this class, I applied for 30 days trial of one trusted CA and tested it with that cert. http://lamp-dev.com/smime-email-encryptionsigning-using-zend_mail/100

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but don't you normally encrypt with the public key of another person and this person decrypts with his private key? Not sure what happends if you encrypt with a private key but I guess you could decrypt it with the public key and would be like plaintext... ?

Comment: Encrypting with the private key is similar/assimilable to signing. Anyone who has the proper public key (which could be "anyone") can decrypt the stuff.

Comment: @PiTheNumber: I did not mean you to encrypt with someone else's public key, I said you can encrypt with YOUR private key and end your public key to everyone for decryption. I'm also not 100% sure, but I believe it is sent along with your cert in an email.

Comment: @Alexey Public key is sent in an email but as Romain said it would be like signing, not really encypting because everyone can decrypt it.

Comment: All, yes, sorry, I see the issue now, please disregard my comments.